# How to run specific Kernel in jupyter hub from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, kernel, jupyter, jupyterhub

Assume I have a script 'test.py'. To run this in Jupyter terminal I can simply put

```
python test.py
```

However, what if I wish to run this with K8s cluster rather than Python. Is there any way to execute with a specific Kernel from terminal? For example,

```
python --pyspark_k8s test.py
```

The above line is for illustrational purposes :-)

Thanks